# How to persist fields in primaryAddress directly in my table ? In my table I have no primaryAddress column but all fields inside it are columns itself

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

"firstName": "Jane",

"lastName": "Smith",

"middleName": "Linda",

"maidenName": "Welch",

"preferredName": "Linda",

"birthDate": "1967-09-23",

"gender": "FEMALE",

"email": "user@example.com",

"primaryPhone": "555-555-5555",

"primaryAddress": {

```
"addressLine1": "123 Evergreen Terrance",
"addressLine2": "Unit 10001",
"addressLine3": "c/o John Smith",
"city": "Springfield",
"state": "MA",
"postalCode": "55801",
"country": "US"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have fully understood your question, but if you want to save the fields of PrimaryAddress directly in the parent table then put the fields directly in the parent class and remove the class PrimaryAddress.

However, in this situation you should consider to use @OneToOne annotation for PrimaryAddress like the following:

```
@OneToOne
private PrimaryAddress primaryAddress;
```

This annotation creates a second table called *primary_address* and add an additional field called *primary_address_id* in the parent table as foreign key.